# Stored procedure to insert data checking its existence

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am working on a stored procedure, and I am getting confused by this part.

I have `City`, `Zip` and `StateName` columns. I need to add the information in the table and should avoid if it already exists. SO that data wouldn't be replicated in the database.

I have the following code. Please help me to figure out the problem.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sproc_InsertAddressElements
   @City nvarchar(100),
   @Zip nvarchar(10),
   @State nvarchar(40)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF NOT EXISTS (Select c.[Name] FROM Cities c WHERE c.[Name]=@City)
    INSERT INTO Cities ([Name])
    VALUES (@City)
    ELSE IF EXISTS (Select c.[Name] FROM Cities c WHERE c.[Name]=@City)

    IF NOT EXISTS (Select z.ZipCode FROM ZipCodes z WHERE z.ZipCode=@Zip)
    INSERT INTO ZipCodes(ZipCode)
    VALUES (@Zip)

    IF NOT EXISTS (Select s.[Name] FROM States s WHERE s.[Name]=@State)
    INSERT INTO States([Name])
    VALUES (@State)


END
GO
```

I have created and written a procedure as per my understanding. But it is not working as expected.

Comment: If you no longer want your question on the site, just use the `delete` link under it. Please don't edit it out of existence like this. It shows a lack of respect for the people who spent time answering your question.

Comment: @Nick Users can't delete their questions if they have a single answer that's upvoted or multiple answers. :) We prevent deletion in those cases for the same reason you cite regarding destructive edits - it devalues the work of the other users here.

Comment: @Catija Thanks - I didn't realise that. I guess a roll-back is the only thing I can do in this situation then.

Comment: Would you consider marking the answers which helped you to resolve your issue (on this question as well as on your other questions) as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it? This will help other people to identify which answers could be helpfull and help as much people as possible. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more like what you are after, based on the information given.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sproc_InsertAddressElements
@City nvarchar(100)
,@Zip nvarchar(10)
,@State nvarchar(40)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF NOT EXISTS (Select 1 FROM Cities c WHERE c.[Name]=@City)
      Begin 
        INSERT INTO Cities ([Name])
        VALUES (@City)
      End

    IF NOT EXISTS (Select 1 FROM ZipCodes z WHERE z.ZipCode=@Zip)
      Begin
        INSERT INTO ZipCodes(ZipCode)
        VALUES (@Zip)
      End

    IF NOT EXISTS (Select 1 FROM States s WHERE s.[Name]=@State)
      Begin 
        INSERT INTO States([Name])
        VALUES (@State)
      End
END
```

You might want to consider some other data validation steps, but this should get you heading in the right direction.

Get in the habit of using `Begin` and `End` statements correctly too so that the control flow works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The danger of doing a check first and then reacting to it later on is that another process might come by in the meantime and cause an unexpected duplicate. You can solve this by either adding a transaction around the check and the insert and making sure the checked row is locked for the duration. Or you can combine the check and the insert in 1 query (and still do the locking) as they then will work under the implicit transaction.

Something along the lines of

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sproc_InsertAddressElements
@City nvarchar(100)
,@Zip nvarchar(10)
,@State nvarchar(40)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO Cities ([Name])
    SELECT [Name] = @City
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select c.[Name] FROM Cities c WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE c.[Name]=@City)

    INSERT INTO ZipCodes(ZipCode)
    SELECT ZipCode = @Zip
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select z.ZipCode FROM WITH (UPDLOCK) ZipCodes z WHERE z.ZipCode=@Zip)

    INSERT INTO States([Name])
    SELECT [Name] = @state
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select s.[Name] FROM States s WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE s.[Name]=@State)

END
GO
```

Comment: Yes.  the original is not "thread safe".  This post is thread-safe at the entity-level (city, zip, state).....thus a decent answer.so upvote.

Answer (score 0):

ZipCodes and Cities also inherently contain duplicates. I would question how a City could be associated with a set of ZipCodes and State without having every entry.

but yes, all you should have to do is get rid of the line @Allenman pointed out.

Comment: We don't see the entire architecture in this bit of code.  It's possible that each of these tables should only hold unique names, and the relationships are handled in many-to-many bridge tables.